# Script for "battery level reminder"

Tags: shell-script, laptop, battery

I want to plug in the laptop battery charger when the battery level goes down to 40% and then plug it out when the battery charge level reaches 80%. And for that reason, I need a script that would remind me to plug in the charger when the battery level is 40% and again would remind me when the battery charge level reaches 80%. How would be the script? Could anything else do that?

Comment: just out of curiosity what's the rationale behind those numbers?

Comment: Take a look in `/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/`. Or if you're running upower, then `upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0`

Comment: @1_CR - the motivation probably comes from an article such as [this one](http://lifehacker.com/5875162/how-often-should-i-charge-my-gadgets-battery-to-prolong-its-lifespan)

Comment: @1_CR Having seen a prolonged brawl on this topic before, I'm pretty confident that it is true, the extreme end of charge/discharge shortens the (lithium ion) battery life, and apparently 70% is the ideal level (i.e., if you are going to store it for a while, leave it at that). http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/how_to_prolong_lithium_based_batteries

Comment: You can get this info by parsing output from `acpi` (a command that may need to be installed), e.g. `Battery 0: Discharging, 71%, 02:36:19 remaining` (hey look, 71%! Perfect ;).  How you do the alert is up to you, but if you come up with a solution, you can answer your own question.

Comment: If you are using good shell, like `zsh`, then you can put battery charge level into right prompt with `RPS1=$(acpi|grep -o "[0-9]*%")%`. Then you can put red color on it if value is lower then 40 or higher then 80 etc.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one. In my ubuntu 12.04 it is working perfectly.

```
#!/bin/bash
high=$(cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/charge_full_design)
now=$(cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/charge_now)
stat=$(cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/status)
echo -e "scale=1\n$now/$high * 100\nquit"> hi
per=$(bc hi)
per=$(expr "$per" : '\(.*\)\..*')

if [ $stat == Charging ] ; then
    if [ $per -gt 80 ] ; then
            zenity --warning --text="BATTERY IS FULL REMOVE THE CHARGER"
    fi
elif [ $stat == Discharging ] ; then
    if [ $per -lt 40 ] ; then
            zenity --warning --text="BATTERY IS LOW PLUGIN THE CHARGER"

    fi
fi
rm hi
```

Comment: See [Why $(..) is preferred over backticks](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082), the [difference between [ and [[](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031) and sparing the cat with `high=$(</sys/class...`

Comment: @jasonwryan You can edit the answer. Then Thanks for the information.

Comment: It would be a pretty major rewrite: I'll leave it to you if you are interested...